# Start different launcher-activty from MyApplication

Tags: java, android, manifest

**My Code**
In `AndroidManifest.xml` the launcher is set for X activity,

inside `public class MyApplication extends Application` I have:

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
}
```

**What I'm trying to do:**
Inside MyApplication to check if the user is running the app from phone or tablet with the method you can see at the top and go to activity B if it's a tablet, or activity A if it's a phone.

**What I have done so far:**

inside `onCreate()`

```
if (!isTablet(MyApplication.this)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyApplication.this, SplashScreen.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyApplication.this, XlSplashScreen.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Is there a way to omit the launcher Activity in the manifest and let the Application class decide which activity should start?

Comment: You shouldn't have different activities for different screen sizes. Instead, modify the layout file

Comment: They have different logic, so it will be too much code in 1 class

Comment: Why does your splashscreen **(!!!)** contain a lot and different logic depending on screen size?

Comment: not splash, the mainactivity does

Comment: what about activity-alias? can i set it to run different activity instead of the default

Comment: You have SplashScreen.class and XlSplashScreen.class. Why?

Comment: different layout and different methods regarding the lang + getting refresh tokens + user configuration before intent to the right layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new Activity with no layout, and set it as the launch activity. Then, in the `onCreate()` method of this activity, check if it's a tablet or a phone and start the desired Activity.

However, I think you should avoid this approach, and give a look to [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments).

**UPDATE**

You can't make the Application class decide which Activity should be started. The Application class contains common parts of your app that should work even if your app is not being shown. In fact it is often used to set event listeners for notifications, since it happens that for this class to be instantiated even if the app is not on screen.

An alternative solution could be making two different apps, one for phones and the other for tablets. However the Fragments approach is still the best.

Comment: That's what i have right now but from what i understood Application Class is the first context to be created and the last to be destroyed. it surrounds the life cycle of your app. so if there's way to start the right activity right away from that class it would save sometime

Comment: You can't start an `Activity` from the `Application` class, because when the `Application` class is instantiated your app is not always on the screen, but it could be also in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Since your activity is a splash screen, I assume the main difference between two of them is UI configuration and sizes. So the best thing you can do is to run the same activity but have different layout files or resources for different screen resolutions and orientation. This is the right way to work with tablets.

Answer (score 1):

You should be allowing Android to natively handle this for you through folder structure.

> res/layout-sw600dp/   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
>
> res/layout-sw720dp/   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
>
> res/layout-sw600dp-port/   # For 7” tablets in portrait (600dp wide or bigger)
>
> res/layout-sw720dp-port/  # For 10” tablets in portrait (720dp wide or bigger)
>
> res/layout-sw600dp-land/   # For 7” tablets in portrait (600dp wide or bigger)
>
> res/layout-sw720dp-land/  # For 10” tablets in portrait (720dp wide or bigger)

So if you are designing for Portrait with a few landscape variants, then you can make a -land folder.

If you are designing for Landscape with a few portrait variants, then you can make a -port folder.

Or you can simply reply on the size folders and don't create any -land or -port folders if the design works fine for both.

Answer (score 0):

You can display different splashscreens using the `drawable`(-s) folders.

More: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

The application class not intended to call `startActivity(intent)` and etc.